# laravel8 Undefined variable: errors

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sendgrid

I am working on a Laravel Api with Vue js Front end. I have a problem on verify email and reset password. I am sending email using sendGrid In email of reset password button its redirects me to /api/password/reset and this route showing me exception of **Undefined variable: errors (View: Path to/ reset.blade.php** same is the case with verify email its redirect route is  api/email/verify/ which is showing error exception in **Undefined variable: errors (View: Path to/login.blade.php**.

**api.php**

```
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
    
 

       Route::get('users/send-email', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController@sendEMails');
        Route::post('client/search', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ClientsController@searchBy');
        Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
        Route::apiResource('user', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController');
        Route::apiResource('freelancer', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\FreelancersController');
        Route::apiResource('client', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ClientsController');
        Route::apiResource('service', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ServicesController');
        Route::post('service/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ServicesController@update');
        Route::post('client/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ClientsController@update');
        Route::post('freelancer/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\FreelancersController@update');
        
        Route::apiResource('contact_us', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ContactUsController');
        
        Route::post('clients/client-referal', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ClientsController@findReferal');
        
        Route::post('freelancers/search', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\FreelancersController@searchBy');
        Route::post('services/search', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ServicesController@searchBy');
        
        // getting admin users for admin dashboard
        
        Route::get('users/admins', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController@getAdminUsers');
        Route::apiResource('sales_methods', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\SalesMethodsController');
        Route::apiResource('industries', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\IndustriesController');
        
        Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
            Route::apiResource('user_subscribe_client', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\SubscribedUserClientsController');
            Route::apiResource('apply_job', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserAppliedJobController');
            Route::get('users/setup-intent', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController@getSetupIntent');
            Route::post('users/payments', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController@postPaymentMethods');
            Route::post('clients/payments', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ClientsController@showMyPayments');
            Route::get('users/payment-methods', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController@getPaymentMethods');
            Route::post('users/remove-payment', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController@removePaymentMethod');
            Route::put('users/subscription', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController@updateSubscription');
            Route::put('users/update-password/{id?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UsersController@updatePassword');
            Route::post('services/status', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\ServicesController@changeStatus');
        });
```

```
**Web.php**
<pre>

Route::middleware('auth')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.\,-]*');
```

**Vuejs Password reset form action**

```
    async resetPassword() {
          const post = { email: this.resetEmail };
          const response = await axios
            .post("/index.php/api/password/email", post).then((){
    further logic
    }).catch((){
    further logic
    })
```

Comment: Can you share your code ? We can't help you without your code.  Thanks

Comment: @GaryHoubre

**Api.php**

`Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`

**Vuejs Password Button submit for reset Password**

` async resetPassword() {
      const post = { email: this.resetEmail };
      const response = await axios
        .post("/index.php/api/password/email", post)
        .then((response)){
}).catch((){

})`


**in Web.php **

`Route::middleware('auth')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.\,-]*');
`

Comment: Can you edit your post and add detail of code.

Comment: @GaryHoubre code attached if anything else required plz let me know.Thanks